# removing file extensions with bash

Tags: bash

I tried to remove the file extension from `./m161016_023529_42229_c101105162550000001823259804261747_s1_p0.2.bax.h5` but I got `./m161016_023529_42229_c101105162550000001823259804261747_s1_p0.2`. The .2 is sometimes .1 or .3.

This is the bash code:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $(ls -d /work/waterhouse_team/All_RawData/Each_Cell_Raw/RSII_SMRT*/Analysis_Results);
do
  cd $i
  baxs=($(find . -type f -name "*.bax.h5"))

  cat <<EOF
  #qsub <<EOF
#!/bin/bash -l

#PBS -N bax2bam
#PBS -l walltime=150:00:00
#PBS -j oe
#PBS -l mem=50G
#PBS -l ncpus=4
#PBS -M m.lorenc@qut.edu.au
##PBS -m bea

source /work/waterhouse_team/apps/pacbio/setup-env.sh
cd $i;

bax2bam ${baxs[@]} -o ${baxs[0]%%.bax.h5} --subread

EOF

done
```

This is the bash output:

```
  #qsub <<EOF
#!/bin/bash -l

#PBS -N bax2bam
#PBS -l walltime=150:00:00
#PBS -j oe
#PBS -l mem=50G
#PBS -l ncpus=4
#PBS -M m.lorenc@qut.edu.au
##PBS -m bea

source /work/waterhouse_team/apps/pacbio/setup-env.sh
cd /work/waterhouse_team/All_RawData/Each_Cell_Raw/RSII_SMRT72/Analysis_Results;

bax2bam ./m161014_135413_42229_c101104702550000001823259804261737_s1_p0.1.bax.h5 ./m161014_135413_42229_c101104702550000001823259804261737_s1_p0.2.bax.h5 ./m161014_135413_42229_c101104702550000001823259804261737_s1_p0.3.bax.h5 -o ./m161014_135413_42229_c101104702550000001823259804261737_s1_p0.1 --subread

  #qsub <<EOF
#!/bin/bash -l

#PBS -N bax2bam
#PBS -l walltime=150:00:00
#PBS -j oe
#PBS -l mem=50G
#PBS -l ncpus=4
#PBS -M m.lorenc@qut.edu.au
##PBS -m bea

source /work/waterhouse_team/apps/pacbio/setup-env.sh
cd /work/waterhouse_team/All_RawData/Each_Cell_Raw/RSII_SMRT73/Analysis_Results;

bax2bam ./m161016_023529_42229_c101105162550000001823259804261747_s1_p0.2.bax.h5 ./m161016_023529_42229_c101105162550000001823259804261747_s1_p0.3.bax.h5 ./m161016_023529_42229_c101105162550000001823259804261747_s1_p0.1.bax.h5 -o ./m161016_023529_42229_c101105162550000001823259804261747_s1_p0.2 --subread
```

What did I miss?

Thank you in advance

Comment: It appears you want to remove the *first* dot and everything after. Is that true?

Answer (score 2):

Your string manipulation command is only removing the `.bax.h5` part.  To also remove an extra leading dot and digit, use something like `${baxs[0]%%.[0-9].bax.h5}`.

Comment: It's possible all that's needed is `${...%%.*}`

Comment: @glennjackman it looks like he might be getting relative path names that have a leading `./`, so that form trims too much.  He's working in a path that has a wildcard in it, so there's no telling how many additional `.`s might be in the complete file path string.

Comment: A cleaner solution is to use `${...%%.*}` and enforce absolute paths in find by using `find $(pwd) ..."`.

Comment: Using absolute paths won't save you from paths with a `.` in the file name (i.e. `/etc/init.d/subfolder/some_file.2.bax.h5`), which can certainly be the case when there's a wildcard in the search path.  The safest option is to surgically extract the filename and avoid any assumptions about the rest of the string, even if it is noticeably uglier.

Comment: @bta - I see what you mean. Assuming the extension is known to follow that pattern, then I agree with you. Might need more clarity from the OP to be certain.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you want to remove an extension consisting of three dots, e.g. `.2.bax.h5`.  If that's true you can use a parameter expansion for this.  Also, you shouldn't be using `ls` and `find` like you are to process the files.

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s globstar nullglob

for f in **/*.bax.h5; do
   mv -- "$f" "${f%.*.*.*}"
done

exit
```

This will recursively iterate over files matching `*.bax.h5`, starting with the working directory.  Then it removes the extension by starting at the end of the string and removes everything until it sees a `.`, three times in total.